# cast closure map to object with a private constructor in groovy

Tags: groovy, proxy-classes

I am using groovy to create some mock classes for a test case. I am basically creating dummy objects where all the methods return null so that i can run my testcase.

I am using the following syntax:

```
MessageFactory.instance = ["getMessage": {a,b,c,d -> "dummy"}] as MessageFactory
```

So here i am trying to overwrite the singleton instance with my on fake factory object. The **problem is that MessageFactory's constructor happens to be a private method**. This gives me an illigal access exception when i run the code above. Is there a away i can create a proxy in groovy and overcome the private constructor issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have access to the MessageFactory, and are willing to modify it, then you use the standard dependency-injection solution, as detailed here: [mock singleton](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/java/MockSupportingSingletons.aspx)
..Though it's not particularly *Groovy*.

Otherwise, the best workaround I've found is to override the method(s) on the singleton instance itself, like so:

```
@Singleton
class Test{
    def method(){"Unmocked method called"}
}


def test = Test.instance
test.metaClass.method = {-> null}

test.method() // Now returns null
```

Naturally, as a singleton, this instance doesn't change (at least in theory)... So, overriding methods in this manner is effectively global.

**Edit:** Or you can use [GMock](http://code.google.com/p/gmock/), which supports constructor mocking (among other things).